# Database design menu planner application

Tags: database, database-design

My first database ever so I kind of need some help :D

[image: MenuPlannerDatabase]

Before I will ask questions let me try to explain about the application and the database flow.

The application will be a menu planner where you will start with a weekly calendar (planner), you can add dishes manually to the days, or you can push the recommendation button and a recommendation of previous made dish, healthy dish, and your favorite categories/cuisine will be given and you can select from them.   There are two dish sections, one (dish) that has pre insert dish(recipes) and one (mydish) that where you can add your own dish and bookmark dish from the pre insert dish.

People have to log into their account and create a member profile. From the dish section they choose the dish that they can make and those will be saved in the my_dish section.

Some questions
1. Is the current database alright or am I missing stuff?
2. dates. I want users to be able to check the history (and also for the recommendation function) of their made dishes (the one that they added into the weekly calendar planner). Where should I add that information. should I make an extra table for that? Not really sure how to do this.

I might come up with more questions, but am looking forward to seeing your thoughts and ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The schema seems fairly complete, although it looks like you are missing one table which shows which dish the user received on which date (this would have fields id,user_id, dish_id, curdate).

It's not clear - at least to me - what the purpose of the 'time' table is. Is the field 'time' (which is probably a reserved word anyway, so should be changed) in the 'my_dish' table a foreign key to this table? And what's the 'time' field in the 'dish' (should be 'dishes'?) table? How long it takes to prepare a given dish?

Change the name of the varchar field in the 'ingredients' table to 'name' or something similar - otherwise it's confusing.

Comment: Thank you for the date table. I now have to look how I can use the date and add a weekly planner... any advice on this?the purpose of the time table is to show how long it takes to create a dish. I have changed this to 't_time' which stands for total time. this will be linked with the 'dishes' and 'my_dishes'.  I have to join the dishes with the cuisine, time, ingredients, and category tables.

I have changed the varchard field to 'ingredients'

Comment: @DaveyStokhof: If 'the purpose of the time table is to show how long it takes to create a dish', then it is unnecessary. The 'time' field in the 'dish' table shows how long it takes to create a dish.

Comment: but I would like users to select the time by using a list instead of letting them just fill in 90 minutes and 1 hour etc.

Comment: @DaveyStokhof: So just create a combobox with times (5,10,15,20, etc) on the form. It seems unnecessary to create a table of given integers.